# Same code, Wicked PDF produces two different reports on two different computers

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I am using Ruby on Rails to generate a PDF using WickedPDF and emailing it. I have the exact same code on two computers (the code is stored on GitHub and the local instances are up-to-date and exactly the same), but for whatever reason the font being provided within the PDF reports are different. One is Arial, the other appears to be Verdana.

This is the code that's creating the PDF:

```
    header_html = av.render(template: "layouts/report_header", locals: {company_name: company_name, layout: nil)
    footer_html = av.render(template: "layouts/report_footer", locals: {company_name: company_name, layout: nil)
    pdf_html = av.render(:template => "reports/report", locals: {data: data})
    body_pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
      pdf_html,
      footer: {
        content: footer_html
      },
      header: {
        content: header_html
      },
      margin:  {  
        top:               25,
        bottom:            17,
        left:              10,
        right:             10 
      },
    )

    body_path = Rails.root.join("public/#{@project_id}/body.pdf")
    File.open(body_path, "wb") do |file|
      file << body_pdf
    end
```

The contents of `pdf_html` (body of the content) shows this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        p {
            color: #545658;
            font-size: 12pt;
            font-family: "Arial";
            font-weight: 500;
        }
        li {
            color: #545658;
            font-size: 12pt;
            font-family: "Arial";
            font-weight: 500;
        }
        h1 {
            color: #ED1C24;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-family: "Arial";
        }
        th {
            padding-top: 12px;
            padding-bottom: 12px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }

        td {
            color: #545658;
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        table.bordered {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table.bordered td {
            border: 1px solid black; 
        }
        table.bordered tr:first-child td {
            border-top: 0;
        }
        table.bordered tr td:first-child {
            border-left: 0;
        }
        table.bordered tr:last-child td {
            border-bottom: 0;
        }
        table.bordered tr td:last-child {
            border-right: 0;
        }

        tr.bordered:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}

        img.finding {
            position:absolute;
            width:60%;
            height: 40px;
            margin-left: -20px;
            max-width: 100%;
            z-index:-1;
        }

        p.finding {
            display: inline;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 16pt;
            line-height: 1.75em;
        }

        pre code {
            background-color: #eee;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            display: block;
            padding: 5px;
            font-family: "Consolas";
            font-size: 10pt;
            color: black;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello world</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This works just perfectly fine on one computer, but not the other. I have a feeling this issue takes place outside of Rails.

Any suggestions on why this could potentially be giving me different results on two different computers?

Comment: If you do not provide a webfont in your project, you depend on whatever the browser resolves from the `font-family` list. The `font-family` acts as a wish list: *I wish to use any of these fonts, if they are available on your system.". That is why you should always end your `font-family` in a generic one (`serif`, `sans-serif`, `cursive`, `monospace`, `fantasy`). To render the same on any machine, use a webfont.

Comment: I am using the same browser to test the same code on two different servers though is the thing. Is there any reason why, as long as the code is the same, I would get two different results?

Comment: Yes, the browser can have a different default set and browsers do not ship with fonts. They ask them from OS. This might change in time (I'm expecting Chrome to switch to using some default Google fonts at some point as it would provide exactly this - the same experience on any system). In order for a website to render with a different font on different systems it's enough to have the first `font-family` installed on one system and not on the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wicked_pdf` uses [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org). If you want to get the same result on all computers, `wkhtmltopdf` version must be the same on all computers. Probably the version of `wkhtmltopdf` on the computers is not the same.

**UPDATE**

All computers must have `Arial` fonts. If `Arial` font is missing, it may cause this error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I compared the versions and they're the exact same.

Comment: @LewlSauce Have you checked arial font on computer?

Comment: Wow. I cannot believe this. I didn't have Arial installed on the computer!! @demir. That fixed it!!